# How do I set time range (HH:MM:SS) on Y-axis using ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2, visualization, data-visualization

I have data.frame with 3 columns as Name, Variable & Value.
My data.frame is like (each value is comma separated)

```
Name,Variable,Value   
a,cycle1,00:01:67
b,cycle1,00:05:20
c,cycle1,00:28:27
a,cycle2,00:02:58
b,cycle2,00:25:18
c,cycle2,00:27:45
a,cycle3,00:37:09
b,cycle3,00:29:18
c,cycle3,00:53:24
```

I would like to plot a stacked bar chart where X axis is Variable & Y axis is Value

I wrote following script

```
Graph<- ggplot(data = dataFrame,
               aes(x = dataFrame$Variable, y = dataFrame$Value, fill = Name)) +
        geom_bar(stat = "identity")
```

by above script graph is coming but it is not showing full range on y axis even I am not able to change the range with some step value on Y axis.

I tried  by strptime as shown below

```
dataFrame$TimeCol <- strptime(dataFrame$Value, format = "%H:%M:%S")

Graph <- ggplot(dataFrame, 
                aes(x=dataFrame$Variable, y=dataFrame$TimeCol,fill = dataFrame$Name)) + 
         geom_bar(color="black",stat = "identity")
```

Now also desired graph is not coming and on Y axis range is like 2000,2100,2200.....
Then I tried by adding one extra column name TimeInSeconds which was actually conversion of Value column to seconds then write code like

```
Graph <- ggplot(data = dataFrame,
                aes(x = dataFrame$Variable, y = dataFrame$TimeInSeconds, fill = Name)) +
         geom_bar(stat = "identity")
```

Now desired graph with Y axis having proper time range in seconds with step of 1000 is coming.

But in place of time in seconds I want in hh:mm:ss format with proper range & step value. I searched through Stack Overflow, cookbook in R but don't got proper results. Any one if can please suggest some solution.

Answer (score 0):

Hacky, but this works:

```r
library(ggplot2)

m <- matrix(c("a","cycle2", "00:01:57", 
              "b","cycle1", "00:05:20",
              "c","cycle1", "00:28:27",
              "a","cycle2", "00:02:58",
              "b","cycle2", "00:25:18",
              "c","cycle2", "00:27:45",
              "a","cycle3", "00:37:09",
              "b","cycle3", "00:29:18",
              "c","cycle3", "00:53:24"), nrow = 9, ncol=3, byrow=TRUE)

start_time = strptime("00:00:00", format = "%H:%M:%S")
end_time = strptime("01:00:00", format = "%H:%M:%S")
breaks = seq(0, 125, length.out = 6)
labels = c("00:00:00", "00:20:00", "00:40:00", 
           "01:00:00", "01:20:00", "01:40:00")

dataFrame <- data.frame(m)
names(dataFrame) <- c("Name","Variable","Value")
dataFrame$Time <- strptime(dataFrame$Value, format = "%H:%M:%S")
dataFrame$TimeInSeconds <- as.numeric(dataFrame$Time - start_time)

p <- ggplot(data = dataFrame) + 
  geom_bar(aes(x = dataFrame$Variable, 
               y = dataFrame$TimeInSeconds, 
               fill = factor(Name)), stat="identity") +
  scale_y_continuous(
    limits = c(0, 125),
    breaks = breaks,
    labels = labels

    )
p
```

[image]

Comment: ps - I used @jennybryan's [reprex() package](https://github.com/jennybc/reprex) to copy and paste the code and image. Makes life super easy!

Comment: Thanks for answer :). Actually total length of cycle3 is more than ~2hrs but it shows 1:40:00 which is wrong. I understand that you scaled it manually and by setting it 2:00:00 we can get the correct graph. My concern was, Can we plot it without providing scale manually? ggplot2 should be able to automatically add up the timestamps and provide the correct scale. Please suggest if something is missing or wrong.

Comment: Can you please help? I tried to complete it I am not able plot the correct plot.

Comment: Hi Roger - Check the `breaks` and `labels` variables. Notice how breaks goes from 0-125, while labels goes from 0-100 (since 1:40:00 is 100 minutes). To corrrectly label, you need to change the label variable to match the breaks variable in value. labels should contain 6 equally spaced values so that the final value is the text version of 125 minutes ("2:05:00").

That would look odd, so maybe it would be better to change breaks to segments of 30 (`seq(0,150,30)`) and then change your label array to every 30 minutes.

Comment: Thank you very much potterzot for your suggestion. I am getting now correct graph. I have one more enhancement. can we generate Labels dynamically ie if I give value of length.out, starting value of label & by value(time by which increment each time). Then can we generate all label values dynamically( for eg if my length.out is 4, starting value is 00:00:00 and by value is 20 min then labels should be 00:00:00,00:20:00,00:40:00,01:00:00)

Comment: There are several ways you could create an array of labels automatically. The `lubridate` package may help with that.